# How can I "position: fixed" a div properly?

Tags: css

If you'll take a look at my site http://www.metroflatsmiami.com/listing.html, you'll see that I have a floating DIV on the right, but the thing is it's set off the left side. If you resize your window (or have a different resolution), it won't look right. I want it to always be just to the right of the main content DIV, but still scrolling... any thoughts?

**The CSS:**

```
.floating_price_box {
    position:fixed;
    width: 200px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    height: 400px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 1000px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery:

```
$(window).bind("load resize", function(){
   $('.right-block').width($('.main-block').width() - (25));
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. this is probably the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah....why not do `right: 50px` instead of `left: 1000px`?

Comment: I don't think this solves the OP's issue. If you fix it to the right, it will still move with the horizontal sizing of the window. I believe what the OP wants is vertical fixed position, with horizontal relative or absolute positioning. I think the only complete solution would be javascript based.

Comment: Well.. Then there will be a large space between it and the main content div. Ideally, I want it to be to the right of the main div by 25px

Answer (score 1):

If you set the floating_price_box div to have a left value of 75%, it will scale with the page size. It breaks when the browser window gets too small, but the window has to be pretty small for that.

```
.floating_price_box {
    position:fixed;
    width: 200px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    height: 400px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 75%;
}
```

In order to make the sidebar 25px to the right of the main content, you could also do something like this. Add an inner div to your floating price box:

```
<div id='home_search_container'>
     ...content...
</div>

<div class="floating_price_box">
    <div class="floating_price_box_inner">
        Nightly Rate: $90 - $130 (<a href="#">Instant Quote</a>)<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's your CSS:

```
#main {
     float: left;
     margin-right: 25px;
     width: 700px;
}

.floating_price_box {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

floating_price_box_inner {
     border: solid 1px black;
    height: 400px;
    position: fixed;
     top: 50px;
}
```

Basically all this second method does is float the outside boxes to the correct position. Then the inner div is styled to fix the box vertically where you want it.

Comment: Hmm... but this won't be always to the immediate right of the main div

Comment: Edited that part. See the new solution.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to position it like the main content and then use margin to shift it to the side:

```
.floating_price_box {
    position:fixed;
    width: 200px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    height: 400px;
    top: 50px;
    /*left: 1000px;*/
    margin-left : 700px;  /* main column width */
}
```